# Python Django view to return POST-request to client

Tags: python, django, django-views, http-post, django-oscar

I have built a web shop with Django and during payment i build-up a POST-request in the view consisting of necessary payment parameters, which then are sent to the payment gateway, and the payment gateway are happy with the POST-request in general.

So far so good, i want to do this without posting hidden forms visible in the HTML source:code in the browser, with other words i want to build and return the POST-request and data from the Django view to the client.

So i want to do something like this to make sure the POST-request originate from the client and not the server to get around session problem(if its possible to return sessions and act like a man in the middle I'm open for that type of solutions as well):

```
return requests.post('https://payment.gw/PostAPI/Init', data = payload)
```

doing this i get the error:

```
Django Version:     1.8.13
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'Response' object has no attribute 'get'
```

TRACEBACK

```
local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
response = middleware_method(request, response)
local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py in process_response
if response.get('X-Frame-Options', None) is not None:
```

Comment: I'm confused about why you think returning the result of `requests.post()` would make the POST request originate from the client. It won't, of course; `post` is still being called from your view.

Comment: I am wondering if its possible to return the POST-request from the view to the client without rendering HTML, but i guess your answer @DanielRoseman is, its not.